# How to set variable value in AsyncStrorage Function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My approach is when i get value from another page using AsyncStorage.getItem('value') then i want to set value of the variable to the item which i have got from AsyncStorage function. My Code is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
export default class B extends Component {

     static message=()=>{
        AsyncStorage.getItem('value').then((value) => {
            console.log(value) // i have got value in console but i dont know how to set it to variable
            });          
        }
  }
```

Comment: where do you want to set the new value?

Comment: @vikrantnegi007 , Anywhere inside the function

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
export default class B extends Component {

     static message=async ()=>{
        return await AsyncStorage.getItem('value')
        }
  }
```

now you can use message to get the value

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a variable called storeAsynData ,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'; // please change this as asyncstorage as other has been deprecated read the docs once
export default class B extends Component {
constructor(props){
this.state={
storeAsynData:''
}
}
     static message=()=>{
        AsyncStorage.getItem('value').then((value) => {
            console.log(value) // i have got value in console but i dont know how to set it to variable
this.setState({storeAsynData:value});
            });          
        }
  }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: it throws an error saying "B.setState is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

use function like this:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'

export const LOCAL_STORAGE_LABLES = { TOKEN: "TOKEN" }
class LocalStorage {
static storeToken = async token => {
await AsyncStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_LABLES.TOKEN, token);
};
static getToken = async () => {
return await AsyncStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_LABLES.TOKEN);
};
static clearToken = async () => {
return await AsyncStorage.removeItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_LABLES.TOKEN);
};
}
export { LocalStorage };
```

And call wherever you want to use something like this:

STORE TOKEN

```
LocalStorage.storeToken(token),
```

GET TOKEN

```
const _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
     const userToken = await LocalStorage.getToken();
  }



useEffect(() => {
_bootstrapAsync();
 });
```

NOTE: must be call with async and await function  because its return promise